# Multiple Inner Join on different tables in MS ACCESS

Tags: mysql, ms-access

HI i have a patient information table and a master look up table, patient info contains the value data and its text is fetched from mstMasterLookup table.
The following code sample was working fine in mysql but in access its causing error.

can any one provide suggestion on this. how to acheive this functionality in Access

```
    SELECT 
   PatientInformations.[Study_Id], 
   tblHospital.Text_data as Hospital, 
   tblGender.Text_data as Gender
FROM 

PatientInformations

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT text_data,Value_data
            FROM mstMasterLookup
            WHERE mstMasterLookup.Table ='Hospital'
            AND Is_Active = true) tblHospital
                ON tblHospital.Value_data =cstr( PatientInformations.Hospital_Id)

INNER JOIN  (SELECT text_data,Value_data
            FROM mstMasterLookup
            WHERE mstMasterLookup.Table ='Gender'
            AND Is_Active = true) tblGender
ON tblGender.Value_data =cstr( PatientInformations.Gender);
```

Comment: Access is a pain for this The solution is normally to create views for your subselect, and then join against the views.

Comment: not being current on Access, but a few things come to mind... Does Access recognize "true" (and "false"), additionally cstr() for converting a value to string --- is this too supported or do you need to find similar functionality in conversion in Access... Again, Access is not my front-line dev language/querying... just offering suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT P.Study_Id, 
       H.text_data AS Hospital, 
       G.text_data AS Gender
FROM (PatientInformations AS P 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT text_data, Value_data 
               FROM mstMasterLookup 
               WHERE Is_Active and Table="Hospital") AS H 
   ON P.Hospital_Id=CSTR(H.Value_data)) 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT text_data, Value_data 
               FROM mstMasterLookup 
               WHERE Is_Active AND Table="Gender") AS G 
   ON P.Gender=CSTR(G.Value_data);
```

While this works, you should be careful when editing it, since Access doesn't understand this syntax, and keeps changing parenthesis () into [].

I think that the problem was that you didn't use the "AS" clause for the table aliases.